# Jenkins - GitHub - Selenium

Tags: github, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

Dears,

Kindly help on the below issues which I am facing when trying to run my selenium test present in github via Jenkins from windows environment.

Issue 1: From the JENKINS > Global Tool Configuration section > GIT section,
the Path to Git executable is by default set to "git.exe" which is giving me the error

```
There's no such executable git.exe in PATH: C:/Program Files (x86)/RSA SecurID Token Common, 
C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath, C:/windows/system32, C:/windows, C:/windows/System32/Wbem, 
C:/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/, C:/Program Files/ActivIdentity/ActivClient/, C:/Program Files (x86)/ActivIdentity/ActivClient/, 
C:/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/, C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/.
```

Issue 2: Also when I am trying to configure a new job from jenkins by choosing Git from the Source Code Management. I am specifying the repository URL:

```
git@github.com:Bimlesh1681/AmazonIndia.git
```

Which is giving me the error:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h git@github.com:Bimlesh1681/AmazonIndia.git HEAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Git is not correctly installed on your Windows machine (wrong configuration or wrong install).

On my Windows nodes, I followed this process to install Git using msysGit:
http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html

It works well and you have nothing to declared on your Jenkins server.

Comment: I have not installed GitHub in my windows but accessing it directly from https://github.com/ where I can created my repositories.

Comment: You have to install a Git client for Windows. Otherwise, it will not work.